# Explicit $L_\infty$-operations on Hochschild cochains of $A_\infty$-algebra

Tags: hochschild-cohomology, a-infinity-algebras, l-infinity-algebras

It is well-known that the Hochschild cochain complex $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$ of an associative algebra $A$ carries a lot of structure.  In particular: a differential, a cup product, and a bracket, which make the Hochschild cohomology $\mathrm{HH}^*(A)$ into a Gerstenhaber algebra.  For concretenes, I have in mind that we're using the standard bar complex model for $\mathrm{CC}^*$ throughout.

If $A$ is now an $A_\infty$-algebra instead, the differential and cup product on $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$ become the first two operations of an $A_\infty$-structure.  There are neat explicit formulae for the higher operations written down in lots of places.  There is also a nice formula for the bracket, and I understand that it fits into an $L_\infty$-structure (or, more fancily, a $G_\infty$-structure) on $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$.  However, I have not been able to find explicit formulae for the higher $L_\infty$-operations written down anywhere.  I have only been able to find more abstract discussions, eg at the level of operads.  I believe that in principle one could extract formulae from these, but this is a bit beyond me at present!  Similarly, one could presumably get formulae by strictifying $A$ to a dg-algebra, but this seems like it would get messy.

**Question 1.** Are there explicit formulae for the higher $L_\infty$-operations on $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$, when $A$ is an $A_\infty$-algebra?

**Question 0.** Are these higher operations in fact all zero?  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to generalise the formula for the $\mathfrak{l}_2$ operation to higher $\mathfrak{l}_k$, and if the higher operations all vanished then it would explain why I've failed to find them written down :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want but the Gerstenhaber bracket is a (graded) Lie bracket on the Hochschild complex (not yet a compelx) for every module $V$ directly. It needs no structure on $V$ at all and satisfies the Jacobi identity strictly without higher homotopies.

Comment: Thanks @StefanWaldmann - is $V$ an $A_\infty$-module over $A$ in your comment?  What I really want to know is whether the differential and bracket (with vanishing higher operations) give the *correct* $L_\infty$-structure on $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$.  E.g. if you replaced $A$ with a quasi-equivalent dg-algebra, would this result in a quasi-equivalent $L_\infty$-structure on $\mathrm{CC}^*$?

Comment: Oh, sorry: I should have used your notation: $V = A$. The point is that the Gerstenhaber bracket only depends on the underlying linear structure of your $A$, not on any sort of algebraic structure. So the question is perhaps how to encode additional structures like $A_\infty$ on your $A$ in the Hochschild complex. This results in e.g. the Hochschild differential plus additional stuff, but the Gerstenhaber bracket was already there from the beginning of time.

Comment: Ah, great, I see now, thanks!  It seems like there really should not be any higher $L_\infty$-operations then.  I'm not sure how to check this (i.e. check that the resulting $L_\infty$-algebra quasi-isomorphism type of $\mathrm{CC}^*(A)$ is an $A_\infty$-algebra quasi-isomorphism invariant of $A$), since functoriality of Hochschild cochains under $A_\infty$-algebra quasi-isomorphisms is a bit messy, so I will leave the question open in case anybody else has suggestions for this.